# How do I migrate data from Team Foundation Server to Visual Studio Online?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'd like to take advantage of Visual Studio Online but I have been using Team Foundation Server on-premises and would like to migrate my data (version control, work items, test cases, and test results) to get my team started with our history.  How do I do that?

Comment: BTW - I realize I answered my own question... It's a very frequent question that I've been getting so wanted to contribute back.  Here's some additional guidance on answering your own questions:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Team Foundation Server Integration Platform](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=%22Team%20Foundation%20Server%20Integration%20Tools%22&f%5B0%5D.Value=%22Team%20Foundation%20Server%20Integration%20Tools%22&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=3) is available as a free platform for migrating/synchronizing data between TFS servers and with Visual Studio Online.

The ALM Rangers have an article in MSDN Magazine with a walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj130558.aspx

There are a couple of limitations from what I understand:

- Takes some work to get up and going but the walkthrough helps out a lot
- This tool does migrate test cases but you need to run the [UpdateSharedSteps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/broken_shared_steps_link_after_migration_from_tfs_integration_platform/archive/2012/11/05/broken-shared-steps-link-after-migration-from-tfs-integration-platform.aspx) tool from the product team.
- Not actively invested in as new features in Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Online lights up

Comment: This tool DOES migrate Test Cases. You need to run a script to fix links in Shared Steps but that is available from the Test Team blog.

Answer (score 0):

There is a <strike>free</strike> migration utility from migrating data from Team Foundation Server on-premises to Visual Studio Online available from OpsHub:  http://aka.ms/OpsHubVSOMigrationUtility.

It allows you to migrate team project(s) from TFS 2010, TFS 2012, and TFS 2013 including the history of:

- Version Control
- Work Items
- Test Cases

It handles the most common scenarios by making smart assumptions that are good for most scenarios.  For those with more advanced scenarios, the [OpsHub Integration Platform](http://aka.ms/OpsHub) is commercially available and helps with synchronizations, custom business rules during migrations including customized process templates, and migration/integrating with other ALM platforms like IBM, Atlassian, HP, etc.

[image: OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility]

Comment: For this tool you should read "smart assumptions" as "hard coded limitations". Test the results before you migrate in production... it may not work for you.

Comment: @MrHinsh, looks like the OpsHub team is looking through them and removing several of the limitations.  Definitely agree with your suggestion for testing migrations - no matter what tool you use including rolling your own, you want to test your migrations several times before flipping the switch for real on your team.

Comment: And we should mention it is a *free* tool, you're not having to pay for anything :)

Comment: As is the TFS Integration Tools :) Free with more features! Rename Team Projects, Reorganise source control, convert work item types, and change process... however with features comes complexity. If you just need to move a vanilla Team Project as is with no complexity then the OpsHub tool should be good enough... run into issues however and you should switch to the TFS Integration Tools..

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to build your own migration utility using the [Team Foundation Server SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx). You can use the Client Object Model to read data from your TFS server and then write it to your Visual Studio Online account.

[image: Extending Team Foundation Server]